# How to fill a geographical column (PostGIS) with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, postgis

I have this SQL query which works properly :

```
UPDATE my_table SET geography = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(my_table.longitude, my_table.latitude), 4326)::geography;
```

But i'd like to know a way to do this in a Ruby method (filling my geography type column with lon/lat data (lon/lat are 2 other columns)).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just found a way to do it in Ruby but i find it a little dirty : `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE my_table SET geography = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(my_table.longitude, my_table.latitude), 4326)::geography")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this api activerecord-postgis-adapter; it manage all the fields using activerecord.

https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter

Or you can use this other which is not over activerecord in case you aren't using rails.

https://github.com/sabman/postgis_adapter